# Looping exception handling

Tags: java, loops, exception

I'm trying to use try-catch statements within a loop so that the user is asked to enter proper values until it is done. I'm currently doing it within a while(true) loop but this has been both discouraged and restricted by our lecturers. Could anyone tell me another way of doing this with a piece of sample code?

I'm aware that this is not the most efficient way to do it. But as of right now this is my problem. Any help would be appreciated

```
class Players {
    private static Map<String, Integer> golferInfo = new LinkedHashMap<>(Main.playCount);
    static Scanner uInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    static void addPlayers(String player) {
        String newPlayer = player;

        while (true) {
            try {
                if (!golferInfo.containsKey(newPlayer)) {
                    golferInfo.putIfAbsent(newPlayer, 0);
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Name currently exists please enter a new name");
                    newPlayer = uInput.next();
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Please enter an appropriate name");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your current code?

Comment: What about a `do {} while (condition)` ?

Comment: Please add your code snippet

Comment: Dont explain what code is doing, show us that "discouraged" code please.

Comment: I have added the code above. Ideally the function should reject any existing names, blank statements and number only inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're using your `if` statement as your loop invariant, instead of the loop's condition, itself. To compensate for this, you could invert the logic of your `if` statement, keeping the scan inside the loop with the `try/catch` and put the `newPlayer` into the list after the loop when you've successfully scanned. As such, I think that you could just get away with something like the following code:

```
while (golferInfo.containsKey(newPlayer)) {
    System.out.println("Name currently exists please enter a new name");
    try {
        newPlayer = uInput.next();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter an appropriate name");
    }
}
golferInfo.putIfAbsent(newPlayer, 0);
```